# regex find string between two strings

Tags: javascript

How can i find a string between two strings with regex for example i want find `example.com` in string `https://example.com/path` OR `http://example.com/path`

```
var str = "https://example.com/path";
str.match(/(?!http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(.*)(?!\/)/g);
```

Comment: Why use regex?  `new URL("https://example.com/path").host`

Comment: Why would you use RegExp for this, instead of the built-in [`URL` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use URL

```js
const url = new URL("https://example.com/path");
console.log(url.hostname)
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to know if the string contains it ?

```
console.log(!!('https://example.com/path'.match(/example\.com/)))
```

Also, check this :
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

might be useful for you

Comment: No, i mean any string between http:// [here] /path